# Checkbox behaviour in parent element

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo

I have clickable div with checkbox inside it. I want that some action performes after click on checkbox or parent div.

I find just this solution but I think it's not the best way to do this. I don't want that the event on parent element performes repeatedly. I get previous checkbox state `myCheckbox.get('checked')` in parentDivCheckBtn click-handler but changed checkbox state in checkbox-handler and code for this handlers very similar.

```
function saveSettings(){
                        var valueCheckbox = !myCheckbox.get('checked');
                        valueCheckbox.set('checked', valueCheckbox );
                        myUtil.someAction();
                    }

myCheckbox.on('click', function(e){                     
                        var valueCheckbox = myCheckbox.get('checked');                          
                        myUtil.someAction();
                        e.cancelBubble = true;
                        e.stopPropagation();    

                    });

var parentDivCheckBtn = $('#parentDivCheckBtn');
    parentDivCheckBtn.on('click', function(event){                      
        saveSettings();                     
});
```

Does it exist any way to make it simple and clear?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onChange event for the checkbox.

```
require(["dijit/form/CheckBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(CheckBox){
    var checkBox = new CheckBox({
        name: "checkBox",
        value: "agreed",
        checked: false,
        onChange: function(b){ alert('onChange called with parameter = ' + b + ', and widget value = ' + this.get('value') ); }
    }, "checkBox").startup();
});
```

Comment: I can't use the onChange event because on parent div click I change checkbox value. It's like infinite loop.